# Getting a list of changelists attached to a job

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to print out a list of the change list numbers (and optionally descriptions) that are attached to a particular job in perforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`p4 fixes`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/fixes.html) command:

```
p4 fixes -j <job>
```